# Property of the riemann stieltjes integral

Tags: integration

I want to show that, if $f \in \mathbf{R}(\alpha)$ in $[a, b]$ and there exists $M>0$ s.t.
$|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ then

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f d\alpha \right| \leq M(\alpha(b)- \alpha(a))$$

it is useful to see that by properties of the integral

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f d\alpha \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f| d \alpha \leq \int_{a}^{b} M d \alpha= M( \alpha(b)-\alpha(a))$$

It's as simple as that, isn't it?

Comment: Bingo. Simple as that. You can also use the definition to get this.